# Why creating an lvalue is one of the benefits of returning a reference in C++?

Tags: c++, lvalue

I am reading some C++ text at the address: https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~chris.szalwinski/archives/oop244.071/content/custo_p.html.
In the section RETURNING A REFERENCE, the author wrote:

"
**Returning a reference from a function has two intrinsic benefits**:

- efficiency
- creates an lvalue

"

I can understand the first benefit (efficiency), but do not understand why is the second one.

As the author explained, I can understand that what is `lvalue`, but I do not understand what is the relationship between the `lvalue` and returning a reference from a function so that `lvalue` becomes a benefit?

Comment: Either it's not obvious, the author has no idea what he's talking about, or he has a weird definition of the word "benefit." I don't know which because I can't see why that's a benefit either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That simply means that you can *assign* something to the result of the function. Consider this example:

```
int& foo() {
  static int x;
  return x;
}

void bar() {
  foo() = 42;
}
```

Instead of `int`, this works with class objects as well, of course. The point is that by returning a reference to `x` the *caller* can directly assign the locally scoped variable in `foo`. This is what the author means by saying that a reference return value "creates an lvalue".

By the way, the example actually has an application, as it solves the *[static initialisation order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)* for more complex types than `int`.

#### Edit

As for the "benefit", there are several ways to interpret this. Either it is a way of making your code more readable (as opposed to the same functionality implemented with pointers) or that you can use operations that can only be applied to an lvalue, which would not be possible if you would not return a reference/pointer but received an argument:

```
struct X {
  int a;
  int b;
};
class Y_withoutRefs {
  private:
    X x;
  public:
    void setXa(int a) {
      x.a = a;
    }
    int getXa() {
      return x.a;
    }
    void setXb(int b) {
      x.b = b;
    }
    int getXb() {
      return x.b;
    }
};
class Y_withRefs {
  private:
    X x;
  public:
    X& getX() {
      return x;
    }
};

void dosmth() {
  Y_withoutRefs ywo;
  Y_withRefs yw;
  ywo.setXa(50+ywo.getXa());
  yw.getX() += 50;
}
```

Comment: @Seth: because it allows you to do something you otherwise couldn't.

Comment: That's not really a benefit. You could do it extremely easily (and more intuitively for your users) with slightly more code.

Comment: Anyway, this answer broadens my knowledge. Thanks all for your effort.

Comment: @ipkiss: That's great to hear :)

Comment: @Seth: You basically have two choices. A get/set pair, or returning a pointer. I don't see how either is "more intuitive", unless you're catering to users who don't understand references. And either way, an alternative syntax is a benefit in and of itself.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: Well a get/set pair has not the same functionality, as you restrict the operators to the assignment operator. As I added to my post, the caller may want to access the `+=` operator whatever else. In this way, it actually provides something that could not be accomplished without returning a reference/pointer to the *hidden* object.

Comment: It's less intuitive to assign to the result of a function call. You don't see that very much, whether it is more convenient or not. I don't really agree that that's a benefit, but whatever :)

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: I bet you have done this quite often, without realising it (assuming you worked with the stl a bit). The deref-operator of iterators gives you a reference to the content of the container. So if `it` is an iterator and you say `*it = 7` then you assigned to the result of a function call!

Comment: @bitmask yes, but not with the `()` syntax. It makes a difference. It is natural to assign to a pointer dereference, which is what the iterators make it look like you're doing.